# force.start() initialises x, y, px and py to NaN in force layout of d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to write a wrapper library of D3 constructs and have hit a hurdle for the following one http://vallandingham.me/gates_bubbles/. This is written in coffee script which I translated into javascript. Here is the code:

```
(function () {
var $, DD3;

DD3 = window.DD3 = {};

$ = jQuery;



function AJAX(uri, cons) {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(uri);
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        cons.data = data;
        cons.generate();

    });
}
// Other constructs
DD3.Bubble_Force = (function(){
    function Bubble_Force(options){
        if (!(this instanceof DD3.Bubble_Force)) {
            return new DD3.Bubble_Force(options);
        }
        if (typeof options.element === 'string') {
            this.el = $(document.getElementById(options.element));
        } else {
            this.el = $(options.element);
        }
        if (this.el === null || this.el.length === 0) {
            throw new Error("Graph placeholder not found.");
        }

        var div = this.el[0];           
        var _THIS = this;

        Bubble_Force.prototype.width = options.width !== "undefined" && options.width !== null ? options.width : $(div).parent().width(),
        Bubble_Force.prototype.height = options.height !== "undefined" && options.height !== null ? options.height : 500;

        Bubble_Force.prototype.data = typeof options.data === "string" ? {} : options.data;

        Bubble_Force.prototype.generate = function(){
            var layout_gravity = -0.01,
                damper = 0.1,
                vis = null,
                circles = null,
                force = null,
                fill_color = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["low", "medium", "high"]).range(["#d84b2a", "#beccae", "#7aa25c"]),
                year_centers = {
                                "2008": {
                                    x: this.width / 3,
                                    y: this.height / 2
                                  },
                                  "2009": {
                                    x: this.width / 2,
                                    y: this.height / 2
                                  },
                                  "2010": {
                                    x: 2 * this.width / 3,
                                    y: this.height / 2
                                  }
                               },
                max_amount = d3.max(_THIS.data, function(d) {
                  return parseInt(d.total_amount);
                }),
                radius_scale = d3.scale.pow().exponent(0.5).domain([0, max_amount]).range([2, 85]),
                center = {
                  x: this.width / 2,
                  y: this.height / 2
                },
                nodes = [];

            var d;
            for(d in this.data){
                d = this.data[d];

                var node = {
                  id: d.id,
                  radius: radius_scale(parseInt(d.total_amount)),
                  value: d.total_amount,
                  name: d.grant_title,
                  org: d.organization,
                  group: d.group,
                  year: d.start_year,
                  x: Math.random() * 900,
                  y: Math.random() * 800
                };

                nodes.push(node);
            }


            nodes.sort(function(a,b){
                return b.value - a.value;
            });

            console.log(nodes);

            vis = d3.select(div).append("svg").attr("width", this.width).attr("height", this.height).attr("id", "svg_vis");
            circles = vis.selectAll("circle")
                        .data(nodes, function(d) {
                          return d.id;
                        })
                        .enter().append("circle")
                            .attr("r", 0)
                            .attr("fill", function() {
                              return function(d) {
                                return fill_color(d.group);
                              };
                            })
                            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                            .attr("stroke", function() {
                              return function(d) {
                                console.log("circles entered");
                                return d3.rgb(fill_color(d.group)).darker();
                                }
                            })
                            .attr("id", function(d) {
                              return "bubble_" + d.id;
                            });
                function charge(d){
                                return -Math.pow(d.radius, 2.0) / 8;
                            };


                function move_towards_center(alpha){
                    return (function() {
                      return function(d) {
                        console.log(d.x);
                        d.x = d.x + (center.x - d.x) * (damper + 0.02) * alpha;
                        console.log(d.x);
                        return d.y = d.y + (center.y - d.y) * (damper + 0.02) * alpha;
                      };
                    });
                }
                force = d3.layout.force()
                          .nodes(nodes)
                          .size([this.width, this.height])
                          .gravity(layout_gravity)
                          .charge(charge(d))
                          .friction(0.9)
                          .on("tick", function() {
                              return function(e) {

                                return circles.each(move_towards_center(e.alpha))
                                            .attr("cx", function(d) {

                                                return d.x;
                                            })
                                            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                                                return d.y;
                                            });
                            };
                        });
                force.start() //x, y are correctly set when this line is commented out but then force layout is not displayed
                function display_group_all(){
                        force.gravity(layout_gravity)
                         .charge(charge(d))
                         .friction(0.9)
                         .on("tick", (function() {
                              return function(e) {

                                return circles.each(move_towards_center(e.alpha))
                                            .attr("cx", function(d) {

                                                return d.x;
                                            })
                                            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                                                return d.y;
                                            });
                            };
                        })());
                        force.start();
                }
        }   
        if(this.data.length) this.generate();
        else AJAX(options.data, this);

    }
    return Bubble_Force;
})();

}).call(this);
```

When the following snippet of code is executed, the values of `x`,and `y` are NaN.

```
var d;
            for(d in this.data){
                d = this.data[d];
                //console.log(d);
                var node = {
                  id: d.id,
                  radius: radius_scale(parseInt(d.total_amount)),
                  value: d.total_amount,
                  name: d.grant_title,
                  org: d.organization,
                  group: d.group,
                  year: d.start_year,
                  x: Math.random() * 900,    //setting x to NaN
                  y: Math.random() * 800     //setting y to NaN
                };
                //console.log(node);
                nodes.push(node);
            }


            nodes.sort(function(a,b){
                return b.value - a.value;
            });

            console.log(nodes);
```

I have tried giving `x` and `y` some hard-coded values but they are still being set to NaN. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Commenting out force.start() resolves the NaN issue but then nothing is displayed.

Comment: Is "radius" set correctly? Most commonly, I experience this error if the scale is not set up properly. If it encounters an error while assigning the radius, the script might never get as far as setting x/y.

Comment: The radius is being set correctly. On further checking I found out that when I comment `force.start()`, `x` and `y` are being set to proper values. However, they are set to NaN when the line is un-commented.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel : console.log(Math.random()) returns a random value as expected.

Comment: If even hardcoded values given NaN then obviously it's not a problem with `Math.random()`.

Comment: `Math.random() * 900` returns a float value. But almost always `x` and `y` coordinates should be integers. Try this: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 900)`

Comment: as juhana said, some other part of code must be overwriting the values for x/y. Debugging (watch) might help.

Comment: Dude, you got it wrong. It's `console.log(Math.random)`, not `console.log(Math.random())`. If it doesn't show `function() { [native code] }` on your console, something is **VERY** wrong. Also, watch for changes on the `x`/`y`.

Comment: I did console.log(Math.random) and it shows `function random()`. I logged the value of each node in the for loop, just after x and y are set. Their values are `NaN`. I mentioned in my previous comment that proper values are set when `force.start()` is commented out. Maybe this is causing the problem.

Comment: use tool to convert CS to JS, http://js2.coffee/, i just converted code from here http://vallandingham.me/gates_bubbles/coffee/vis.coffee and it looks fine! might easier than to hand craft.

Comment: @saj Tried that. Doesn't work for my case.

Comment: @HumptyDumptyEIZ there's this function being called in this script try adding to ur code http://vallandingham.me/gates_bubbles/js/script.js

Comment: @saj The function `addCommas()` is being called for displaying info when a bubble is hovered over which I do not require right now.

Comment: It's difficult to be sure without seeing how you are using this constructor, but if you are pushing data into nodes while the layout is running, then you will definitely have this problem.  If a `.tick()` occurs after adding the nodes and before `force.start()` is called, then any arrays closured in the layout (e.g. `charges`) and any of the extra members added to the nodes array by `.start()` (e.g. p.x/y), will be `undefined` and any calculation in `force.tick()` involving these missing members will be NaN. The solution is to call `force.stop()` before adding nodes and `force.start()` after.